# What is the best way to import a small sized MySQL Database to Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, import

[Schematics Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9nE3.png)

I have created a simple 5 table SQL Database for my family company. It consists of tables: Companies, CompanyDetails, Contacts, Continents, Products.

I am focusing on making a frontend interface for displaying the Companies using drop-down menus for Type, Category, Country and/or Continent.

Since, I already learned a bit of Python, I decided to use the Django framework to get it done. Now, I realize that importing a legacy DB using inspectDB is a non-trivial exercise in Django. Would it be a better/easier approach to just create a fresh model in Django and import csv s obtained from the database into it as there are only 5 tables in the first place? If yes, how do I do this in Django?
Edit: I've used composite foreign keys for some tables. Is it possible to use this in Django?

Comment: Why is it a "non-trivial exercise"? That is exactly what inspectdb is for.

Comment: Handling multiple databases seems to a long process at least according to this tutorial https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2017/03/21/using-django-with-an-existinglegacy-database/

Comment: Why do you need multiple databases?

Comment: Doesen't Django add alls sorts of admin tables to the database?

Comment: Yes. Why is that a problem?

Comment: So, if I want to use another framework later down the line. Is it as easy as just dropping those extra tables, or will it mess up everything?

Comment: Also, in the models generated by inspectdb, can I throw away the Django generated models, or do I need to reorder them too?

Comment: Inspectdb shouldn't be showing Django generated models, as those won't be created until you run migrations.

Comment: Awesome, got it. I clearly used inspectdb after the migrate. Thank you for your help. Apologies for my noobiness.